# Why aren't user control borders same for each edge?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, border

I have a custom UserControl that has a TextBox inside of it. But the user control borders have a problem. Because they are not symmetric at all. That's the what I say below.

[image: Custom Control]

As it can be seen, the border-right and border-left are not same, as the top and the bottom. Gray colored thing is the textbox. How can I make the borders same for all edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the BorderStyle property of the user control is set to Fixed3D, set it to FixedSingle to draw the border around the user control or set it to NONE.
Note:

1. The first picture is with the Fixed3D.
2. The second is the FixedSingle.
3. The last is when the BorderStyle is set to None.

[image]